# div show on home page only not in paged

Tags: homepage, paged

im using this piece of code to show my div only on homepage.

```
<?php if ( is_front_page() ) :?>
```

but it's shown on pagination 2, 3 and so on. is there any help regarding to fixing this issue?

Comment: did you try with `is_home()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you guys for quick response.
Here is the code that worked for me.

```
<?php if( is_home() != '' && !is_paged()) { ?>
    div here
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home

```
<?php if(is_home()): ?>

 <div>Your div.</div>

<?php endif;?>
```